# UIActivityViewController takes a lot of time when first appears

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I am displaying a `UIActivityViewController` in my app, but the first time I do this, it takes ages to pop, like 5+ seconds. The next times I don't have this issue however.

Here is how I call it:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: nil)
    avc.excludedActivityTypes = [.airDrop]
    self.present(avc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I also tried adding this trick in AppDelegate, but with no luck:

```
let avc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: ["start"], applicationActivities: nil)
avc.becomeFirstResponder()
avc.resignFirstResponder()
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Did you find any solution?